# Laravel выдает ошибку при выполнении DB::statement

Tags: sql, laravel

Мне нужно запустить команду по оптимизации БД:

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE telescope_entries;
```

При запуске этой строки

```
DB::statement('OPTIMIZE TABLE ?', ['telescope_entries']);
```

получается ошибка:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
(Connection: mysql, SQL: OPTIMIZE TABLE telescope_entries)
```

Почему - не понятно. Пробовал запускать другие `DB::statement`, и ошибка возникает только когда используется подготовленное выражение на DDL:

```
DB::statement('OPTIMIZE TABLE telescope_entries'); // SQL работает
DB::statement('SELECT ?', [1]); // Bindings работает
DB::statement('OPTIMIZE TABLE ?', ['telescope_entries']); // Это - не работает
```

Не знаю, может DDL не позволяет использовать подготовленные выражения? Если без низ, то как тогда правильно сделать, чтобы не допустить SQL инъекцию, ведь название таблицы может быть любым.

Comment: сам спросил - сам ответил. Нельзя имена таблиц параметрами задавать (`select * from ?` тоже не будет работать, параметры передаются на этапе выполнения запроса, а до этого надо построить план выполнения, что  не возможно без имени таблицы). в DDL параметры тоже сомнительны

Comment: как сделать - проверять по "белому списку" имен таблиц. Вообще интерфейс для таких оптимизаций не должен допускать ввод от каких нибудь левых пользователей. зы: если у вас InnoDB, то optimize будет заменен на ребилд

Comment: Спасибо @teran. 1. А вообще есть какая-то операция типа addslashes() / DB::quote(), но для экранирования имени таблицы? 2. В MySQL имена таблиц заворачиваются в "`", а Postres следует ANSI стандарту и использует одинарную кавычку. Как средствами Лары указывать в сыром SQL запросе тот вариант, который подошел бы под текущую БД? Переводить MySQL в режим ANSI не хотелось бы, может есть вариант проще

Comment: 3. `optimize будет заменен на ребилд` - знаю. А есть SQL чтобы сразу сделать ребилд? `REBUILD TABLE ...`?

Comment: `alter table xxx engine=InnoDB` учтите что на больших таблицах это будет долгий процесс.

Comment: @teran а есть какой-то другой способ уменьшить физический размер файла данных? Сейчас удаляю старые записи и использую OPTIMIZE TABLE, и да, работает медленно. Конечная цель - регулировать размер БД на диске, чтобы не выйти за дисковую квоту. В MongoDB есть capped collection - нужно похожее решение. Таблица используется для журналирования, отказаться от БД в пользу записи в другое место невозможно - требование бизнеса

Comment: если очищаете старые данные в журналах, то можно партциировать таблицу по времени и грохать старые партиции целиком , optimize не потребуется. Можете еще row_format=compressed поставить,если там текстовых данных много (с учетом того. что эта инфа просто лежит, а не активно читается и используется, т.к. распаковка потребует некоторых доп. затрат).

Comment: @teran спасибо, хорошее решение. А как-то можно средствами SQL понять сколько данных занимает каждая партиция, что бы в скрипте принять решение. И будет ли это работать на Postgre?

Comment: в `information_schema.partitions.data_length` есть размер в байтах (надо суммарно брат с `index_length`). Про postgre не знаю механизмы.